# Visual Studio 2010 issue around global::System.Exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Somehow today when I input:

```
try {} catch {}
```

I get this:

```
try 
{       
}
catch (global::System.Exception ex)
{
}
```

But it should be just:

```
try 
{       
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

What happens? How I can back to `Exception`?

Comment: What's the problem? Just the template? You understand that the two have the same meaning in code, right? (Assuming you don't have some other type called `Exception`.)

Comment: What is the actual issue? If you are referring to a syntax difference; they are the same. You can just delete the `gloabl::System.` part to get back to `Exception`.

Comment: @SamuelSlade The issue is that I didn't change stuff but I got gloabl::System.  Why is it?

Comment: @Terminador Sorry, thought I understood this but maybe not. Are you getting a compiler error at `catch (Exception ex)`?

Comment: @Terminador What do you mean you "didn't change stuff"? `global::System.Exception` and `Exception` (assuming the latter is from the `System` namespace) represent the same type.

Comment: @Yuck. No ... gloabl::System.Exception   appears instead of System.Exception

Comment: @SamuelSlade. Yes. But why it happens? Eraly it was without global::

Comment: Sounds like a code snippet.  The typing mistakes ("gloabl", "Eraly") might be a clue but hard to nail down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following progam results in `global::System.Exception` if you place the cursor between the braces for the `Main` method and type `try` and press [TAB] twice, i.e. triggering the code snippet for a try/catch.

Therefore - do you have a class called `Exception` defined somewhere in your project / referenced assemblies, or do you define a top-level namespace `System`? One of these, or a combination could cause this. Also note that the code sample lists no `using` statements so that could be a contributing factor.

```
namespace ExceptioWuh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }

    namespace System
    {
        class Exception : global::System.Exception
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Not having the custom type called `Exception` present results in the `catch` being `catch (System.Exception)` so I think it's quite a specific scenario that causes this.